# Show route direction in Google Maps

Tags: android, maps

```
           googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(
                    new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(latitude), Float
                            .parseFloat(longitude)))
                            .title("Marker").title(title));
            **googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng( Double.parseDouble(latitude1),  Double.parseDouble(longitude1)),
                    new LatLng( Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude)))
            .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));;**
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    cameraLatLng, 17));
```

So basically that's what I have done, but what that code does is it draws a line from a source to a destination. However, I do not want to draw a line, I just want to show route direction.

like this picture http://s7.postimg.org/dwdbkq6h7/Screenshot_2015_04_14_20_40_58.png

Comment: This question is a bit broad, and you have a bit more work ahead of you.  Take a look at these tutorials:  https://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part5  and: http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to find a route between two points.